# How to manage navigation in Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento

I want to know if is there an easy way to manage navigation in magento through the admin panel, without having to edit an XML file.

Comment: Exactly what wand to do?? Please explain.

Comment: you need to be provide more information about your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use the following extensions:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/responsive-custom-menu.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sidebar-navigation-menu-professional.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/menu-manager.html